# Query for available package versions with pacman

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

I am wondering if there is option to use pacman to query for available package versions.

If I want to install a specific version of a package I can do this by

```
pacman -S "bash>=3.2"
```

However, this requires that I already know what package versions are available. I would like to have something like this:

```
pacman -Q(?) bash
```

returning something like this:

```
> bash=3.2
> bash=3.1
> bash=3.0
> bash=2.0
```

If there isn't an option via pacman, is this information available somewhere else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arch Linux is *rolling-relase*, mean it's only provide the latest, so you can't specify which version you want to download. However you can search and download the package manually from **Arch Linux Archive** at https://archive.archlinux.org/ then install manually

```
pacman -U package-name-0.0.0.tar.xz
```

Note that this method will not handle version conflicts, you need to change the version of dependencies by yourself.

[**Downgrade**](https://github.com/pbrisbin/downgrade) is a tool to downgrade (or select version you say it) one or multiple packages. You can also query available package version on your [cache](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#Cleaning_the_package_cache) and [Arch Linux Archive](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_Linux_Archive)

Comment: Hi. Can you confirm me there is no cli tool to do such a search? Yours is the only meaningful answer. But the procedure seems quite cumbersome and error prone. Thanks a lot anyway for the great answer.

Comment: @EnzoR see [my new answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/749648/357604) and in fact [the man page](https://archlinux.org/pacman/pacman.8.html) under the "Sync" command "search" option. Yes, there is a CLI tool to do a regex search: `pacman`, no less. You can also search in the online package database from a web browser: https://archlinux.org/packages/

Answer (score 0):

Yudaka's answer is the best answer to the question in response to the detail about package *versioning*, but it doesn't answer the main question as framed by the question title about **searching for package versions**. I'm providing this answer for those that will come here as a result of the title, and I think this could be of some use to the OP as well.

##### Search for package versions

First I will just point out that `man pacman` *does* say that a version specifier can be used when searching for packages:

> You can also specify version requirements: `pacman -S "bash>=3.2"`.
> Quotes are needed, otherwise the shell interprets ">" as redirection
> to a file.

Presumably there may sometimes be multiple versions, like in circumstances where different versions of a package co-exist because they have significantly different functionality; such as Python 2 and Python 3. If only one version of that package is available in the database, then presumably the command will not install it if the version specifier excludes it.

##### Search for packages on the website

At the cost of being preachy, please consider searching on the website first. I know other package manager search functions have been depreciated and removed because the traffic volume from command line searches was too much. Especially consider *not* batching online search as automations can be unhelpful in increasing usage.

- **https://archlinux.org/packages**

It's certainly easy to remember the web address.

##### Online package search from command line

It's not prominently documented, but `pacman` *can* search for available packages: packages that haven't been downloaded and installed yet, and it can do this with a regex:

```
pacman -Ss <regex>
```

E.g.:

```
pacman -Ss bash
```

There's also a regex example in the `man` page:

```
pacman -Ss ne.hack
Search for regexp "ne.hack" in package database.
```

##### Mnemonic for the `-Ss` option

Pacman does have a "Q" for "query" command, but I believe that is restricted to querying *installed* packages only, and there's a lot of flexibility and power there for managing your install base, finding orphans, and culling and pruning your packages and left over files.

This search is not a "query" because it targets the online database. It's therefore a "sync" command: "S" for "sync". If you've come to terms with "syncing" when you're installing hopefully you'll have a flexible enough mind to put that in your memory when your command needs to reach out online, and then just remember that it's the "s" option for "search": `-Ss`: "Sync search".

##### How Good is `pacman`?

Well, I dunno, but `pacman` seems to have it all. There was no "no it can't" answers in the whole scope. Pacman delivers. Power to the Arch.